# Spaces sharing all higher homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is it possible that two topological spaces share all higher homotopy groups, but are not homeomorphic? I should note that I have not studied much in the way of the theory of higher homotopy groups; I merely know of the groups' existence, and was wondering what could be said, in broad terms, about such a case.

If such a case is possible, an example would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be interested in this, then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem

Comment: It should be pointed out that Whitehead's Theorem requires that the isomorphisms are all induced by a map, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can happen. A simple example is to take $X=S^1\vee S^2$ and $Y$ to be a circle with a two spheres attached each at a different point. Then $Y$ is a double cover of $X$, so it shares all higher homotopy groups $\pi_n$ $n\geq 2$. (Here we use the fact that a covering map induces an isomorphism on all higher homotopy groups.) Also $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(Y)=\mathbb Z$, so $X$ and $Y$ have the same fundamental group as well.

Comment: Actually, a really trivial example is $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=[0,1]$. To make the question interesting you probably want to ask that $X$ and $Y$ are not homotopy equivalent.